# Restore scrollbuffer and tabs in iTerm as Terminal.app does

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I love the restore functionailty of the Terminal.app when the app crashes or I need to restart my computer, Terminal.app will show me the recent scrollbuffer for the tabs I have open with a - **[Restored]** - key word below. So I know what I did in each tab.

Unfortunately, I did not find a comparable option in iTerm2 and I do not mean the Save Window Arrangement option. What I want is the restored scrollbuffer including all tabs when the app closed as the Terminal.app does.

Now why do I want that so badly in iTerm when Terminal does what I want? I want to be able to use the awesome tmux integration of iTerm ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is implemented in the night builds of iTerm2. Follow the [instructions to enable window restore](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3528#note_1202968) and you should get what you want.

Comment: Thank you Birger that looks very promising and exactly what I want I will give it try :)